# trying to delete a file, doesnt delete or throw error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, .net

At the end of the month I copy a file over to a different location and remove the original:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(fileLocation + PLU.FolderPath, destinationFilePath, true);
System.IO.File.Delete(PLU.FolderPath);
```

The file copies but it doesnt remove, it doesnt remove because the file doesnt exist.
PLU.FolderPath holds: PLU_104.DAT, which is why I need to use the 'fileLocation + PLU.FolderPath' in the copy.

Shouldnt it throw an error if it doesnt delete though? Even if the file it is looking for is not there?
I've tried it inside a try catch but it still doesnt throw an error:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(fileLocation + PLU.FolderPath, destinationFilePath, true);

                                try
                                {
                                    System.IO.File.Delete(PLU.FolderPath);
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                    {
                                        Log.Quiet("Didnt delete" + e.Message);
                                    }
```

Comment: According to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx no exception is thrown if the file is not found.
If you want an exception, then ou're going to have to use the File.Exists method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Msdn

> If the file to be deleted does not exist, no exception is thrown.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)